# install4J: where can I see application logs when redirection is not working

Tags: install4j

I configured install4j to redirect log files :

```
stderrFile="${installer:sys.appdataDir}/myApp/logs/error.log" redirectStdout="true" stdoutFile="${i${installer:sys.appdataDir}/myApp/logs/output.log"
```

Problem is that recently I have reports that my app is not functioning properly because for some Windows users, the folder `${installer:sys.appdataDir}/myApp/` is not created. I am not sure what is happening here and the problem is that I don't have access to my log files that were supposed to be dumped in that folder. Is there anywhere else on the system those logs files can be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directory for the redirection file cannot be created, a FileNotFoundException will be thrown by the launcher. If the directory exists, but the redirection file cannot be written, no redirection will be performed, but the launcher will start.

I would suggest to create an additional launcher without redirection and set it to console mode. In that way the output will be displayed on the terminal.

Comment: this is what I ended up doing